# Is there a way to check my quest?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I keep forgetting what I have to do, so I'm just asking if there's anyway to check the quest. Maybe a button I'm forgetting because I'm stupid, something like that.

Comment: I didn't play fallout:nv (shame on me), but in fallout 3 and 4, you could open the pip boy and select the quest which was then tracked on your radar.

Comment: There's a quests tab on the pip boy in New Vegas too.

Answer (score 3):

Under the "Data" tab of your Pip-Boy, there is a "Quests" page.

Here, you can select which quest you want to be active, and review the current objective for all the quests you've started. The quests with a square icon to the left of them are active. Click on the quest name to toggle it between active and inactive.

Your active quests will have their quest markers show up on your Pip-Boy map, and also on the compass at the bottom of your screen.

Answer (score -3):

You need to keep checking your PipBoy to track quests. There is no "easy track quest" mod for it.